# django drawbacks of using autoescape?

Tags: django

Was wondering if there are any drawbacks to using autoescape. I like having to put some html into my models sometimes so I can have more power over formatting the text fields.

Is there any performance issues with having a lot of {% autoescape %} tags in the template

Comment: `{% autoescape %}` is `on` by default. So there's no point putting that tag in your templates.

Comment: I think you might be confusing `autoescape` with the `safe` template filter which allows arbitrary HTML, including JavaScript tags to be output, which **can** be exploited.